# Multidimensional array into string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a result set from a DB that returns the following array.... how do I implode this into a comma delimited string?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 11
        )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$t = array_map(function (array $a) { return $a["user_id"]; }, $original_array);
$result = implode(",", $t);
```

(PHP 5.3+, the closure must be turned into a regular function for earlier versions)

Comment: Don't think there is a need to confuse beginner PHP programmers with constructions of such complexity.

Comment: @Fra Seriously? This is "complex"?

Comment: Yes. Closures is not something beginners can understand very well.

Comment: @Fra I don't see why. `Scheme` is often taught in introductory programming courses. Do you think the beginner PHP programmer cannot understand something a freshman CS undergraduate can?

Comment: Do you see the level of the question asked? The guy doesn't know how to restructure a given array. Forget Scheme. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach($myNestedArray as $item) {
   $resultArray[]=$item['user_id'];
}
$resultString = implode(',', $resultArray);
```

Works on all recent PHP versions.